# Firestore Function Trigger wont trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

For some reason the onWrite Event is not triggering in Firestore.

[image: Img]

Here you see the look of the function in the Firebase Website. Here is the trigger inside of my function ts file:

```
exports.newCommentCounter = functions.region('europe-west1').database.ref('posts/{PostID}/comments/{CommentID}').onWrite(async(change) => {
```

The logs are empty like the function never got triggered.

For example adding a Document to `posts/postidblabla/comments/commentidblabla` wont trigger the function.

Comment: Issue found check Comment below

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, this comes from the fact that you are using `async` in a Node.js **6** Cloud Function.

The following should work:

```
exports.newCommentCounter = functions.region('europe-west1').database.ref('posts/{PostID}/comments/{CommentID}').onWrite((change, context) => {
 => {})
```

Also, note that since v 1.0, `onWrite()` takes two parameters, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database.

So, in addition to the change proposed above, please double-check that you have a recent version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions.

Comment: I found the issue, its because I used .database.ref instead of .firestore.document, I just messed up that part im sorry for wasting your time on that such a stupid mistake...